# Как узнать голый адрес без ЧПУ

Tags: php, веб-программирование, apache, nginx, http

Голый адрес страниц: `http://example.com/index.php?route=bla-bla&id=123`

Адрес с чпу: `http://example.com/bla-bla/123`

Есть ли возможность узнать голый адрес страницы через какие-нибудь инструменты (напр. расширение разработчика в хроме)?

Или как поисковики узнают голый адрес? Например, если в webmaster яндекса ввести `http://example.com/bla-bla/123` то он знает что эта страница на самом деле доступна по `http://example.com/index.php?route=bla-bla&id=123`, или это исключительно вопрос индексации?

P.S. изменение url идет на уровне кода ( не .htaccess )

Comment: В общем случае нет, нельзя. Как страницу распознал Яндекс – возможно, Яндекс ранее её уже видел под "голым" адресом и чтобы не дублировать, приассоциировал к тому, что видел – но это лишь догадка.

Comment: возможно там   одностраничник на   html5  c   в индексе, а страницы подгружаются аяксом?

Comment: @eri в этом случае я понимаю как посмотреть заголовки, если через аякс, и скрипт напрямую обращается. Но в данном случае это скорее академический интерес, и скорее всего D-side выше ответил верно